# Iterating SQL statement By For Loop (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

In my test database, I am attempting to do an iterative `UPDATE` statement based on multiple criteria.

In my table I am trying to update, `tblSales_Language`, I have the columns
`Sales
_LanguageID , Language_ID, Sales_CountryID, SalesID,  & CountryID`

As a reference table, I am using `tblSales_Country`, which has `Sales_CountryID, CountryID, SalesID`.

My goal is to `UPDATE` the columns in tblSales_Language, which have information but all columns except for `Sales_CountryID`- this information I am attempting to draw from the reference table `tblSales_Country`

Without further ado, my current code is as follows:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim SQL As String
For i = 1 to 5
SQL = "UPDATE tblSales_Language 
&_ SET tblSalesLanguage.SalesCountryID = "
& DLOOKUP("Sales_CountryID", "tblSales_Country",  "[SalesID]" = i)"
Exit For
```

My code does not register as syntactically correct, does it have to do with the fact that I do not have a `WHERE` in my statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your existing code, there are a few issues to correct: (a) line-continuation; (b) SQL syntax; (c) missing 'Next' in Loop; (d) never executing your SQL. So using your code:

Option 1:
If 'SalesCountryID' is not numeric, you will need to enclose the

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim SQL As String
For i = 1 To 5
    SQL = "UPDATE tblSales_Language " & _
            "Set tblSalesLanguage.SalesCountryID = " & _
            DLookup("Sales_CountryID", "tblSales_Country", "[SalesID]" = i) & _
            " Where SalesID = " & i & ";"
    Debug.Print SQL
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL
Next
```

Option 2:

Create a query (using Design Wizard) that will join the two tables on the common key, filter by SalesID = 1 to 5; execute that query (or SQL)